# How to POST data in in REST API using J meter

Tags: jmeter

by HTTP request 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw3rt.png)base url is: http://124.124.21.165:8093/FieldApp/Service.svc/

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks good, I would suggest just adding a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of `application/json`

[image: JMeter HTTP Header Manager]

Also it would be good to add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request and response details (don't forget to remove or disable it when it comes to running the load test assuming large amount of users)

Check out [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) test plan for step-by-step instructions

Comment: it is not working in request it shows..........
[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 593
Host: 124.124.21.162:8093
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_121)

Comment: In samp[le request it show....Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 404
Response message: Not Found

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 1565
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 09:37:05 GMT

Comment: HTTP Status code 404 means that URL doesn't exist, double check your HTTP Request path

Comment: Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-03-01 17:21:01 IST
Load time: 13
Connect Time: 2
Latency: 13
Size in bytes: 1412
Sent bytes:779
Headers size in bytes: 204
Body size in bytes: 1208
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

Comment: Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 11:51:01 GMT
Content-Length: 1208

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5. Either your request is not correct or it is the error on server side. Check response data and server logs to figure out what's wrong